# Fit an equation to data by minimizing mean squared error by minimizing sum of the squared error

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying the estimate fitting parameters that can minimize sum of the squared error between the predicted and test values.

To do this, I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize`

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import scipy.optimize as spo


# Initial guess of the parameters 
LOGGMIN = 120 # variable 1 
LOGGMAX = 104 # variable 2
BETA = 0 # variable 3
GAMMA = 50 #variable 4
 
C1E_O = -504 #variable 5
C2E_O = 2012 #variable 6


ReferenceTemperatureE_O = 21

x0 = [LOGGMIN, LOGGMAX, BETA, GAMMA, C1E_O, C2E_O] # Initial guess as a list

# Importing the data from Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Mahmoud Khadijeh\Desktop\MasterCurve.xlsx', header=None)
K = ((np.dot(-C1E_O,df[0]) + C1E_O*ReferenceTemperatureE_O)/(C2E_O+(df[0]-ReferenceTemperatureE_O)))
df['log f'] = np.log10(df[1])
df['Test LogG'] = np.log10(df[2])
df['WLF Shift Factor Log alphaT'] = K
df['WLF Reduced Frequency log(fr)'] =df['log f'] + df['WLF Shift Factor Log alphaT']
df['Predicted logG*'] = LOGGMIN + ((LOGGMAX - LOGGMIN)/(1+np.exp(BETA + GAMMA *(df['log f']+df['WLF Shift Factor Log alphaT']))))
df['Predicted Error'] = ((df['Test LogG']-df['Predicted logG*'])/(df['Test LogG']))**2

# Defining an objective function (Sum of the square error),, The function that we have to minimize
def objective(SE):
    global Sum_Error
    LOGGMIN = SE[0] #Variable 1 that we have to optimize 
    LOGGMAX = SE[1] #Variable 2 that we have to optimize 
    BETA = SE[2] #Variable 3 that we have to optimize 
    GAMMA = SE[3] #Variable 4 that we have to optimize 
    C1E_O = SE[4] #Variable 5 that we have to optimize 
    C2E_O = SE[5] #Variable 6 that we have to optimize 
    Sum_Error = df['Predicted Error'].sum()
    return Sum_Error
    
sol = spo.minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})


print(df)
print('sum= ', Sum_Error)
print ('Solver', sol)
```

I want to optimize the variables `[LOGGMIN, LOGGMAX, BETA, GAMMA, C1E_O, C2E_O]` so I can obtain the minimue value of the function (some of the squared error)

However, the output that I got is :

```
[60 rows x 9 columns]
sum=  16837173.60030545
Solver      fun: 16837173.60030545
     jac: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 7
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 120.,  104.,    0.,   50., -504., 2012.])
```

As you can see, that the output of the parameters is similiar to the initial guess and the value of the function is very big. It supposed to be close to 0.

Any Help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not recalculating your objective actually.

The code should be something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import scipy.optimize as spo

# Initial guess of the parameters
LOGGMIN = 120  # variable 1
LOGGMAX = 104  # variable 2
BETA = 0  # variable 3
GAMMA = 50  # variable 4

C1E_O = -504  # variable 5
C2E_O = 2012  # variable 6

ReferenceTemperatureE_O = 21

x0 = np.array([LOGGMIN, LOGGMAX, BETA, GAMMA, C1E_O, C2E_O])  # Initial guess as a list

# Importing the data from Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Mahmoud Khadijeh\Desktop\MasterCurve.xlsx', header=None)

# Defining an objective function (Sum of the square error),, The function that we have to minimize
def objective(SE):
    LOGGMIN = SE[0]  # Variable 1 that we have to optimize
    LOGGMAX = SE[1]  # Variable 2 that we have to optimize
    BETA = SE[2]  # Variable 3 that we have to optimize
    GAMMA = SE[3]  # Variable 4 that we have to optimize
    C1E_O = SE[4]  # Variable 5 that we have to optimize
    C2E_O = SE[5]  # Variable 6 that we have to optimize

    K = ((np.dot(-C1E_O, df[0]) + C1E_O * ReferenceTemperatureE_O) / (C2E_O + (df[0] - ReferenceTemperatureE_O)))

    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df['log f'] = np.log10(df[1])
    new_df['Test LogG'] = np.log10(df[2])
    new_df['WLF Shift Factor Log alphaT'] = K
    new_df['WLF Reduced Frequency log(fr)'] = new_df['log f'] + new_df['WLF Shift Factor Log alphaT']
    new_df['Predicted logG*'] = LOGGMIN + (
            (LOGGMAX - LOGGMIN) / (1 + np.exp(BETA + GAMMA * (new_df['log f'] + new_df['WLF Shift Factor Log alphaT']))))
    new_df['Predicted Error'] = ((new_df['Test LogG'] - new_df['Predicted logG*']) / (new_df['Test LogG'])) ** 2

    Sum_Error = new_df['Predicted Error'].sum()
    return Sum_Error


sol = spo.minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})

print(df)
print('Solver', sol)
```